# 8 - How do a get a view then save it with a new value

Tags: 8, views

In an `update_hook()` I need to search all views' displays for a value, then resave them with a new/extra one.  How do I go about this?  What command can I use?

```
$views = Views::getEnabledViews();
foreach ($views as $view) {
  $source_value = '';
  $config = \Drupal::config('views.view.' . $view->id());
  $rawData = $config->getRawData();

  $master = FALSE;
  // Get the display with the draggableviews field.
  // It is a little tricky because the 'default' display is the master.
  foreach ($rawData['display'] as $display_key => $display) {
    $field = isset($display['display_options']['fields']) ? $display['display_options']['fields'] : [];
    if ($display_key == 'default' && array_key_exists('draggableviews', $field)) {
      $master = TRUE;
    }
    if ($display_key != 'default' && array_key_exists('draggableviews', $field)) {
      $source_value = $view->id() . '|' . $display_key;
    }
    if ($master && empty($display['display_options']['fields'])) {
      $source_value = $view->id() . '|' . $display_key;
    }
  }
  if ($source_value) {
    // Save the view with the source value in the sort handler.
    foreach ($rawData['display'] as $display_key => $display) {
      $sorts = isset($display['display_options']['sorts']) ? $display['display_options']['sorts'] : [];
      if (array_key_exists('weight', $sorts)) {
        // **************
        // SAVE VIEW HERE
        // **************
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered a [views sort handler plugin](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Plugin%21views%21sort%21SortPluginBase.php/group/views_sort_handlers/8.4.x) instead?

Comment: It's a temporary thing I need to put in an update_hook().  I do not want to create a permanent file to accomplish this.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for [ConfigEntityBase::save()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Config%21Entity%21ConfigEntityBase.php/function/ConfigEntityBase%3A%3Asave/8.4.x)?

Comment: I think I might have it now calling Views::getView($view->id()) as it returns an ViewsExecutable class, instead of a Views class

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
// **************
// SAVE VIEW HERE
// **************
```

with

```
$view_exec = Views::getView($view->id());
$view_exec->setHandlerOption($display_key, 'sort', 'weight', 'source', $source_value);
$view_exec->save();
```

When you call `Views::getEnabledViews()` it gives you an array of View classes.  What you need is the ViewsExecutable class.   `Views::getView($id)` returns this.

**ViewsExecutable**

> An object to contain all of the data to generate a view, plus the member functions to build the view query, execute the query and render the output.

[Views](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Views.php/class/Views) vs [ViewsExecutable](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21ViewExecutable.php/class/ViewExecutable)

Another good example of using `setHandlerOptions` is in the TestCase

[FieldGroupRowTest](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21tests%21src%21Functional%21Handler%21FieldGroupRowsTest.php)